# How to register View helper

Tags: view-helpers, zend-framework3

How to register View helper using factories?

```
View\Helper\GenerateAnchor::class => GenerateAnchorFactory::class,
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you just need settings in configuration file, but I'll show full road to registering view helpers in Zend 3

First, we need view helper:

```
namespace MyNamespace\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class TestViewHelper extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        // your code...
    }
}
```

If we need inject some dependencies, then we need to create custom factory, however if our view helper doesn't need other services/class then we can skip this step

```
namespace MyNamespace\Factory\View\Helper;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use MyNamespace\View\Helper\TestViewHelper;

class TestViewHelperFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string $requestedName
     * @param null|array $options
     * @return TestViewHelper
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $class = $requestedName ? $requestedName : TestViewHelper::class;
        $auth = $container->get('MyCustomAuth');
        $viewHelper = new $class($auth);

        return $viewHelper;

    }
    /**
     * Provided for backwards compatibility; proxies to __invoke().
     *
     * @param ContainerInterface|ServiceLocatorInterface $container
     * @return TestViewHelper
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $container)
    {
        return $this($container, TestViewHelper::class);
    }
}
```

Last step is to register our view helper in `module.config.php`

```
'view_helpers' => [
    'aliases' => [
        'viewPlugin' => View\Helper\TestViewHelper::class,
    ],
    'factories' => [
        View\Helper\TestViewHelper::class => InvokableFactory::class // Or use your own factory
    ]
],
```

And... in our view template we can use it like this:

**index.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->viewPlugin(); ?>
```